# How to draw only segment of whole image with p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

Is there way to render just segment of whole image with p5.js? Can you please provide an complete example?

Comment: Can you please add a sketch to illustrate your idea?

Comment: i want to be able to use p5.js with texturepacker https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer